# How to call a function from one vue file to another vue file in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have two vue files in different paths like views/core/AppBar.vue and view/entity/edit.vue.I want to call or refresh `Appbar.vue` when a particular event happens.

I don't know how to call or refresh other component and which approach is better?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some code. 
Also read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these two components are in a parent-child relation then you can use $emit from a child component to a parent one and use $refs. to call a child component method directly from a parent component.

If these components are not related closely then you should use the event bus pattern (see examles with creating new Vue()) or if you wish shared data for these components then use a vuex store to store all shared objects.

Comment: "Bus" it the best solution for non component relationships and its also a simplest way. i found a link refer this : https://medium.com/@kashifazmi94/sharing-data-between-component-in-vue-js-acfd71e05815